# git doesn't notice change in image - .jpg

Tags: git

I replaced a .jpg file , which is version controlled by git with a new different file.
When I do `git status` I get no changes for commit.

Is git can't track .jpg files?

Comment: Does the file has the same name ?

Comment: git surely can track content of binary files like JPEG. I'd suggest you to create a pure reproducible example of your problem in a clear repository and then demonstrate it here. Likely there're unrecognized problems/settings in your current repo (e.g. like .gitignore or something)

Comment: Tried to recreate it on a clean git, but, (as expected), no problems there. I copied all .git* files (not dir), but it still was OK (changes did appear on status. What can be different in my original repository?

Comment: Well, I would bet on `.gitignore` somewhere in the directory hierarchy or on `.git/info/exclude`, but actually it's just a guess.

Comment: You may try to clone your original repository (`git clone myrepo myrepo.copy`), and see if the problem persists in the cloned repository. If it does, then the problem is in the repo content (checked in into the repo), if it doesn't - then it's repository settings (look carefully into .git/)

Comment: Same for me....

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and this worked for me:

```
 git rm --cached path/to/image.jpg
 git status
 git commit -a
 git pull origin dev
 git push origin dev
 git add path/to/image.jpg
 git status
 git commit -a
 git push origin dev
```

Answer (score 0):

I got massively stuck on the same issue. Nothing works! The only solution I did was edit the images and added some dots and line literally!